# Android tween animations in material design

Tags: java, android, android-animation, material-design

I'm trying to include tween animation in my material design app but not getting the desired effect.Here is my code:

**Java**

```
 Animation animation= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.fade);

    FloatingActionButton fab=(FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            view.startAnimation(animation);
        }
    });
```

**Android XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.1"
        android:duration="5000"
        android:repeatCount="1"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"/>
```

I want it to fade in and out for 5 seconds but it does it for less than a second.

Comment: Do the developer options-> animator duration scale setting have any overriding effect?

Comment: I guess so coz it used to work before i upgraded to material design support library